# Permission Forbidden when using google authentication API

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-auth-library

When I try to integrate Google Authentication in my project. I'm facing 403 Forbidden error.

With message
**Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

## I am using PHP Codeigniter and this is my code below

```
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
            $client_secret = '###########################';

            $google_client = new Google\Client();
            $google_client->setClientId($client_id);
            $google_client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
            // $google_client->setRedirectUri(base_url('/'));
            // $google_client->setRedirectUri('https://test.com/beta/');
            $google_client->setRedirectUri('https://test.com/beta/user/login');
            $google_client->addScope('email');
            $google_client->addScope('profile');
            if (isset($_GET["code"])) {
                $token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);

                if (!isset($token["error"])) {
                    $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $token['access_token']);
                    $google_service = new Google\Service\Oauth2($google_client);
                    $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
                    $userId=$data->id;
                    $userEmail= $data->email;
                    $userName=$data->name;
                }
            }


            $login_button = '';
            if (!$this->session->userdata('access_token')) {
                $login_button = '<a href="' . $google_client->createAuthUrl() . '"><img class="border p-2 rounded-pill" style="width:3rem;" src="' . base_url("assets/web/image/google_logo.png") . '" /></a>';
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Pwd.png)

It will be really helpful if anyone give me a solution.